# Country flag dropdown based on visitor ip address using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show a dropdown of countries flag with country code, by default it should select the country based on visitor ipaddress, country

Can i do it without any third party api  or using jquery, please help

Comment: to detect user country you have to use api or other way is write your own api ;) via php you can detect user IP address but than you have to call api to check from which country is the ip

Answer (score 2):

To detect the user's country you need lists of IP addresses of all countries and then search for the user's IP in these lists. The IP lists can be provided by third party services.

If you don't want to use a third party API because of high prices, there are free services like this one: https://geolocation-db.com.

If the third party API isn't an option at all, you need to store the IP lists locally, e.g. in an SQL database, and then do search manually. These databases can be found over the Internet.

When you find the user's IP you may show it in any country selector. For example, https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/country-picker-flags.html. It has a property to set a country by default, the found user's country can be set there:

```
$("#country_selector").countrySelect({
  defaultCountry: "<?php echo $userCountryCode ?>"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `geoip_country_code_by_name` through `PECL`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php